# Top level statements: live code suggestion not working?

Tags: visual-studio-code, console-application, .net-6.0, c#-10.0, toplevel-statement

I saw a new feature, the Top level statements that simplifies the entry point of a console application

[In Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)

Yet one simple thing I am not able to get sugestions for: **Using** for namespaces outside this project

After adding the references in the console app's .csproj, I can normally add my using in any class I create:

```
using MyNameSpace.IsThis;
```

Typing Myname... will get Omnisharp to suggest me the namespace

But not in  **Main**. Is this a bug?  in c# or in the live compiler?
I am able to add the using.

And interestingly, if I am using a namespace inside the same project, I get the suggestion while typing

Comment: This looks like an IntelliSense bug. I filed a bug for dotnet/roslyn which you can track at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58470.

Answer (score 0):

It was [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58470) , as Youssef13 pointed